Trying to return forecast values by date and by time using export from a different system
I have an forecast that is exported from our scheduling system that has times on the left and dates at the top with the forecasted numbers under those dates. I'd like to have a formula/search that returns the value corresponding with the date and time interval. The issue is that the dates are below in an odd format. I can't figure out a way to have the data look down for the results.


I have tried a vlookup, xlookup, index and match functions and can't find something that works. Is there something that I can do to work with the export format?

Could you share as markdown table and expected results with given data (plus the actual formulas you tried that didn't work).

Is the bottom what you expect the output to be or an additional export?

I would go with MATCH to find row number and column number for each date and time interval. Then use INDEX+ADDRESS to get the value from the cell reference given row index and column index.

